# How to not wrap contents of a div?

Tags: html, css

I've got a fixed-width `div` with two buttons in it. If the labels of the buttons are too long, they wrap – one button stays on the first line, and the next button follows underneath it instead of adjacent to it.

How can I force the `div` to expand so that both buttons are on one line?

Comment: I can't even login with my OpenID to doctype, so methinks the question best belongs here.

Comment: @nicholaides I agree it would work on doctype but I think it's totally legit on SO as well.

Answer (score 529):

Try `white-space: nowrap;`

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: FYI: According to [MDN's docs on `white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Browser_compatibility), the `nowrap` value is supported in IE 6+, though other values are only IE 8+

Answer (score 79):

A combination of both `float: left;` `white-space: nowrap;` worked for me.

Each of them independently didn't accomplish the desired result.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know the reasoning behind this, but I set my parent container to [`display:flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/display#display_flex) and the child containers to [`display:inline-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/display#CSS_Flow_Layout_display_block_display_inline) and they stayed inline despite the combined width of the children exceeding the parent.

Didn't need to toy with `max-width`, `max-height`, `white-space`, or anything else.

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: This worked for me when other approaches listed above did not. All I needed was `display: flex`. Didn't need anything else.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care about a minimum width for the div and really just don't want the div to expand across the whole container, you can float it left -- floated divs by default expand to support their contents, like so:

```
<form>
    <div style="float: left; background-color: blue">
        <input type="button" name="blah" value="lots and lots of characters"/>
        <input type="button" name="blah2" value="some characters"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your div has a fixed-width it shouldn't expand, because you've fixed its width.  However, modern browsers support a `min-width` CSS property.

You can emulate the min-width property in old IE browsers by using CSS expressions or by using auto width and having a spacer object in the container.  This solution isn't elegant but may do the trick:

```
<div id="container" style="float: left">
  <div id="spacer" style="height: 1px; width: 300px"></div>
  <button>Button 1 text</button>
  <button>Button 2 text</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Forcing the buttons stay in the same line will make them go beyond the fixed width of the div they are in. If you are okay with that then you can make another div inside the div you already have. The new div in turn will hold the buttons and have the fixed width of however much space the two buttons need to stay in one line.

Here is an example:

```
<div id="parentDiv" style="width: [less-than-what-buttons-need]px;">
    <div id="holdsButtons" style="width: [>=-than-buttons-need]px;">
       <button id="button1">1</button>
       <button id="button2">2</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

You may want to consider [overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) property for the chunk of the content outside of the `parentDiv` border.

Good luck!