# How do I get my text to be next to each other not on top

Tags: html, css

I want the google form text to be right next to each other not on top of each other. here is a picture. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf6dk.png. I also need help fix my hover over the text feature. I added an orange hover for when you go over the text it shows where you are but when you do it does not fit the whole div. Here is a picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxMcd.png

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(187, 190, 4);
  font-family: Arial;
}

.navBAr,
ul {
  list-style: none;
  background: #401f99;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}

.navBar,
li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar,
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  padding: 25px 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.navBar,
a:hover {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Movie And Tv Shows Google Form Recomendations</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="background.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="navBar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">HomePage</a></li>
        <li><a href="/mainPages/googleForm.html">Google Form</a></li>
        <li><a href="/mainPages/myMovies.html">Movies</a></li>
        <li><a href="/mainPages/myTvShows.html">Shows</a></li>
        <li><a href="/mainPages/topMovies.html">Top Movies</a></li>
        <li><a href="/mainPages/topTvShows.html">Top Shows</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry if there are grammar mistakes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to not wrap contents of a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703183/how-to-not-wrap-contents-of-a-div)

Answer (score 0):

The "Google Form" string is wrapping because you don't have enough space for it and have CSS attribute `white-space` set to the default `normal`. Override the default to get the desired with `white-space: nowrap;`. More on CSS `white-space` here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(187, 190, 4);
  font-family: Arial;
}

.navBAr,
ul {
  list-style: none;
  background: #401f99;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}

.navBar,
li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar,
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  padding: 25px 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  /* added the below */
  white-space: nowrap;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="navBar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">HomePage</a></li>
    <li><a href="/mainPages/googleForm.html">Google Form</a></li>
    <li><a href="/mainPages/myMovies.html">Movies</a></li>
    <li><a href="/mainPages/myTvShows.html">Shows</a></li>
    <li><a href="/mainPages/topMovies.html">Top Movies</a></li>
    <li><a href="/mainPages/topTvShows.html">Top Shows</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, it worked

Comment: i also have one more question now that's fixed this is happening

Answer (score 0):

Use white-space: nowrap; CSS property.
[Refernec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(187, 190, 4);
  font-family: Arial;
}

.navBAr,
ul {
  list-style: none;
  background: #401f99;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}

.navBar,
li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar,
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  padding: 25px 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap; // add this
}

.navBar,
a:hover {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Movie And Tv Shows Google Form Recomendations</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="background.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="navBar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">HomePage</a></li>
      <li><a href="/mainPages/googleForm.html">Google Form</a></li>
      <li><a href="/mainPages/myMovies.html">Movies</a></li>
      <li><a href="/mainPages/myTvShows.html">Shows</a></li>
      <li><a href="/mainPages/topMovies.html">Top Movies</a></li>
      <li><a href="/mainPages/topTvShows.html">Top Shows</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks, it worked

Answer (score 0):

There wasn't enough room in the containers for the text to span, so it was wrapping.  Here is a solution that instead converts the `ul` to a flex container to make the items go in a row.  After that, we can simply remove the `li` width and it will flow with the padding.  If you do want the items to be wider, just increase the horizontal padding.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(187, 190, 4);
  font-family: Arial;
}

.navBAr,
ul {
  list-style: none;
  background: #401f99;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}

.navBar,
li {
  
}

.navbar,
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  padding: 25px 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.navBar,
a:hover {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Movie And Tv Shows Google Form Recomendations</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="background.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="navBar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">HomePage</a></li>
        <li><a href="/mainPages/googleForm.html">Google Form</a></li>
        <li><a href="/mainPages/myMovies.html">Movies</a></li>
        <li><a href="/mainPages/myTvShows.html">Shows</a></li>
        <li><a href="/mainPages/topMovies.html">Top Movies</a></li>
        <li><a href="/mainPages/topTvShows.html">Top Shows</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```